# Rails: empty nested resource contains implicit entry with nil-initialized fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to embed nested resource (named 'folders') index to parent (named 'user') 'show' viewer, I've found kind of an issue. After doing db creation/migration (when no explicit actions have been done with 'folders' table yet), I create user entry. Right after creation, 'show' method for this user shows me a folder with fields of NilClass. One entry, no matter which user is shown, it always contains this Nil-ed entry by default. I can add other entries, but this one is always presented.

There's also an interesting thing: in rails console @user.folders returns empty array and its #each method works well (i.e. in console all the things work properly, this issue does not appear there).

Here's 'create' method of nested resource:

```
class FoldersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find params[:user_id]
    @user.folders.create params[:folder]
    redirect_to user_path @user
  end
```

users/show.html.haml - parent viewer (user info output is cut off to make code easier to read a bit):

```
Add a folder:
=form_for [ @user, @user.folders.build] do |f|
  .field
    =f.label :name
    =f.text_field :name
  .actions
    =f.submit

%br
User's folders:
%table
  %tr
    %th Name
    %th
    %th
  -@user.folders.each do |folder| # Will make at least one iteration even if 
                                  # no entries have been created yet. Works  
                                  # properly in rails console
      %tr
        %td= folder.name.class ## here will be NilClass in that default entry
        %td= link_to 'Show', user_folders_path(@user, folder)
        %td= link_to 'Delete', [@user, folder], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
```

I'm new in both Rails and web-based applications, so, please, feel free to ask questions if something is not described properly, as well as criticize coding mistakes.

Upd: 
UserController::create method:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your problem is "When you are creating a user entry you are getting a folder entry for this user with nil values. But in console, `user.folders` is giving empty array". If i understood properly, then please give the `create` method of your `UsersController` and the view where the nil entry is showing.

Comment: @SamironPaul My UserController::create is a standard method generated by scaffold. I added it to the question above.
Viewer is already presented above, there're comments describing where exactly does NilClass appear.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue. In your form_for tag you're using

```
@user.folders.build
```

Which is adding an empty folder record to your folders object with an appropriate user_id attribute.

Lower in your code you're iterating through that same folders object and that's why you're seeing the empty record.

If you simply put your form code below your table of folders code you'll see that the empty record is no longer there (because it hasn't been created yet!)